# Saving a modified document (with a modified subdocument array) in Mongoose model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

The code I currently have is:

```
User.findOne(
    {
        "subUsers.email" : userEmail
    },
    {
        subUsers : {
            $elemMatch: {
                email : userEmail                            }
        }
    },
    function(err, user){
        if(user){
            var information = user.subUsers[0].information.id(id);

            information.arrayA.push({someId : "something"});

            user.save(callback(err)); // Also tried information.save()
                                      // without luck
        }

        callback(err);
    }
);
```

This doesn't return any kind of error, but when I check the DB, the new array element hasn't been pushed (the whole document is intact).

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please post your schema.

Comment: I'm not familiar with mongo, but just in case it is related to the issue, the callback of `user.save(callback(err));` is probably being called after the `callback(err);` at the end. So, it is possible the callback is being called twice if there is a `user`. Perhaps you need to `if (user){ ... } else { callback(err); }` or something.

Comment: I definitely forgot an "else". Still not saving, but thank you for the heads up. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, Mongoose is currently not prepared for multilevel nesting in an atomic way.

Therefore, even if it's going back to a kind-of relational database, in this case it's better to split the nesting into at least 2 collections, and reference using the automatically generated ObjectId.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably check out the first faq, here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html

```
Mongoose doesn't create getters/setters for array indexes; without them mongoose never gets 
notified of the change and so doesn't know to persist the new value. The work-around is to 
use [MongooseArray set][1] available in Mongoose >= 3.2.0.
```

So in your case, you want to add this third line

```
var information = user.subUsers[0].information.id(id);
information.arrayA.push({someId : "something"});
user.subUsers.set(0, information);
```

Or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Tried both "set()" and "markModified()". But none of them are working either. :/

Comment: I think there is a subtle error with your code, can you post the updated version using set?

Comment: Even if the "set" worked, it wouldn't be useful in this case, since I'm using id() to retrieve the element in the nested array. It seems I'm in the same situation this other coder is:
https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1754

Do you know of any working example of sub-subdocument saving? I'd be infinitely grateful.